# Getting Started in Auto Repair

Tags: troubleshooting, restoration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Reviving a vehicle that has been idle for a long time.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/125/reviving-a-vehicle-that-has-been-idle-for-a-long-time)
>
> [How to begin learning engine tuning?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/how-to-begin-learning-engine-tuning)

My dad has an old Mazda that has been sitting in the garage for a long time.  He probably hasn't even started it in over 10 years.  I've been thinking about starting the project of repairing it for two reasons.  One I want to drive the car and two I want to learn more about auto repair.

The problem is I don't know where to even start.  Pretty much the only thing I've ever done to my car is change the oil, so I know next to nothing about car repair.  I'm not expecting to be able to go from a broken car to a working one in a weekend and I figured the old car would be a good place to do some trial and error, since its not being driven anyways.  But before I start tearing it apart and attempting to replace things I would like to have some basic information.

My question is how do you get a basic set of car repair knowledge.  Is there a book or website you recommend?  I don't expect to become a master mechanic after reading a book but it would help to know what roles the different parts play and some common diagnostic techniques.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question has been answered in two other questions, so I am going to close it as a Duplicate. Please review the answers in the two questions linked above. If you have a specific question after you have read the other answers feel free to post the specific question. If you have questions about the site or why this question was closed please ask on [meta](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: My question want how to repair an idle vehicle it was where a good place to get started learning about auto repair is. I had read both Of those posts prior to posting.