# How to Get Basic Car Repair Knowledege

Tags: troubleshooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Started in Auto Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/getting-started-in-auto-repair)

I'm looking for some teach yourself sources for auto repair.  I'd like to start restoring an old car in my dad's garage, but I don't have the knowledge to start.  I've read some of the other posts about restoring a vehicle that hasn't been used in a long time, but they don't really help without the knowledge of how you go about identifying and replacing the parts mentioned in the posts.

I'm looking for books, websites, videos, etc that would give me a good foundation in auto repair.  Obviously there is no substitute for real experience, but thats why I intend to practice on the car in my dad's garage.  I just want to have some basic book knowledge before I go and get my hands dirty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have questions about the site or why this question was closed please ask on [meta](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Larry I can't ask a question in meta because I don't have the rep. You closed the other one citing questions related to starting idle cars. That wasn't what that question was about.  So I posted another one and you closed it because it was in reference to the one that you closed already.  I don't understand what the problem is with my question.  If you could explain it I would appreciate it.

Comment: You have enough rep to open a meta question now.

Comment: @rhololkeolke: Larry also pointed you to [this question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/how-to-begin-learning-engine-tuning) which has a couple of great answers that apply to your situation. I *highly* recommend checking it out, and if you have a specific follow-up question, then asking that - you stand a better chance of getting an answer that helps you if you can tell us how existing answers didn't...